# Ruby Shoes - Problem with edit list and if-statement

Tags: ruby, listbox, if-statement, shoes

I want to run a program which changes the background depending on which gender you choose in a edit list.

```
Shoes.app do 
    para "your gender"
    list_box :items => ["female", "male"], 
    width => 120, :choose => "weiblich" do |list|
        @gender.text = list.text
    end

    @gender = para "#{@gender}"

    button "change colours" do

        if @gender ="female"
            background (deeppink)
        else @gender ="male"
            background (dodgerblue)
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is - whatever I do, if I use the if-statement, suddenly always "female" is in the variable and my background is pink, altough when I pick "male". If I just do

```
...
button "change colours" do
para @gender
end
....
```

the right gender is in the variable @gender. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `if @gender == "female"` and `if @gender == "male"` - note the two `=` symbols.

You're performing an assignment, not testing equality.